# Corda allowedToSeeCriteria filter always returns empty with consumed states

Tags: blockchain, corda

I have an issue using the AllowedToSeeStateMapping. To me it looks that it only works with unconsumed states but not with the consumed ones (if I query the vault for consumed states using the allowedToSeeCriteria it always returns an empty list). Does anyone have the same problem, or is it intended to work like this?

Answer (score 0):

The default values for status and relevancyStatus are UNCONSUMED and ALL respectively. (https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os/4.8/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/node/services/vault/QueryCriteria.kt)
When you build a vault query expression the sub-criteria don't copy those values from the root, so you have to include them explicitly for every sub-criteria expression.
So yes, I'm guessing allowedToSeeCriteria is intended to work that way, but you could reverse engineer the logic to set status as CONSUMED or ALL of any sub-criteria in that expression.